Math formula uglly characters spacing
I'm having difficulties to type correctly math formulas without them appearing with spaces between the formulas characters. Thank you for any help.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}  %%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, babel}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} %

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Préambule}

\[id\_comprend\_2\_caracteres = (lettre+\_) \cdot \, (lettre+chiffre+\_)\] 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

$id\_comprend\_2\_caracteres$ de l'identificateur devient \emph{id}:

\[id = (lettre+\_)(lettre+chiffre+\_)^*\] 

\begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(162.5,0)
        {
            \vector(0,9){0.5cm}
        }
        \put(1.6,-0.2)
        {
            \emph{absence du point, symbole de la concaténation}
        }
\end{picture}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[chiffre = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9\]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[nombre = chiffre^*\]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[nombre = chiffre \cdot chiffre^*\]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[pchiffre = 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9\]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[nombre = pchiffre \cdot chiffre^*\quad : 0 \notin nombre\] ou
\[nombre = 0 \cup pchiffre \cdot chiffre^*\quad : 0 \in nombre.\]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\[nombre = chiffre \cdot chiffre^*\]

\[dec = nombre \cdot nombre\]

\end{document}


Anyone reading this will read chiffre as c\cdot h\cdot i\cdot f\cdot f\cdot r \cdot e. If you want to use variable names like this, wrap each name in \mathit or \mathrm or even \mathtt.

by design the math italic font separates letters so that adjacent letters do not look like a word. Usually def means d times e times f not a word def \mathit{def} would be the italic word def, using the text italic font in math mode

Using the environment [ XX ] allows to insert automatically a newline after the formula. \mathit{def} doesn't allow that.

What daleif and David said is that, if lettre is a single variable, you should use \mathit{lettre}. This has nothing to do with the math environment ($...$, \[...\], etc.).

@cProg I'm not understanding what you mean by \mathit{def} not allowing a newline after the formula.

You shouldn't use math italic for the job, but text italic in math, which is done through \mathit.
I can offer a command \tv that eases the input. Digits inside the argument are printed upright and _ is replaced by \_.
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}  %%
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning, babel}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tv}{m}
 {% textual variable
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([[:digit:]]) } { \c{mathrm}\{\1\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \c{_} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \mathit{\l_tmpa_tl}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Préambule}

\[
\tv{id_comprend_2_caracteres} = 
(\tv{lettre}+\_) \cdot (\tv{lettre}+\tv{chiffre}+\_)
\] 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

$\tv{id_comprend_2_caracteres}$ de l'identificateur devient $\tv{id}$:
\[
\tv{id} = (\tv{lettre}+\_)
\underset{%
  \underset{\makebox[0pt]{\itshape\footnotesize absence du point, symbole de la concaténation}}%
           {\makebox[0pt]{$\uparrow$}}
}{\mathstrut}
(\tv{lettre}+\tv{chiffre}+\_)^*
\] 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
\[
\tv{chiffre} = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
\]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\end{document}

Note how I placed the arrow, not with picture.

Some advice: never leave a blank line before a math display and leave one after it only if the text starts a new paragraph.

Just to add: what we can do in OpTeX when we want to use "variables" with italic letters and upright digits.
\fontfam[lm]

\def\tv {\bgroup
   \foreach 0123456789\do{\adef##1{\rm##1}}%
   \tvA
}
\def\tvA #1{\mathbox{\it #1}\egroup}

\nonum\sec Préambule

$$
\tv{id_comprend_2_caracteres} = 
(\tv{lettre}+\_) \cdot (\tv{lettre}+\tv{chiffre}+\_)
$$ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

$\tv{id_comprend_2_caracteres}$ de l'identificateur devient $\tv{id}$:
$$
\tv{id} = (\tv{lettre}+\_)
   \mathop{}_{\hbox to0pt{\hss \typosize[8/10]
      \table{c}{$\uparrow$\cr\it absence du point, symbole de la concaténation}
      \hss}}
(\tv{lettre}+\tv{chiffre}+\_)^*
$$ 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.
$$
\tv{chiffre} = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
$$
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Phasellus tempor bibendum ex in placerat.

\bye

The \tv variable is printed in \mathbox. It behaves like \hbox (i.e. the argument is processed in text mode) but it respects the current math size (text/script/scripscript). The digits are defined as active macros (with \rm) before the \tv parameter is scanned. The character _ does not need to be set because OpTeX sets its catcode as letter.
